# how to display data in 'inline' using css?

Tags: css, html

I have list of anchor tags:

```
<a href="#withTagEle"><i 
  class="fa fa-male"></i></span> 10.58.1D.50.1F.FB
  <button class="btn-xs pull-right showOnHover viewInfoOfElement">View</button> 
  <button class="btn-xs pull-right showOnHover editElementInfo">Edit</button>
</a>
```

which looks like this:

[image]

But a few of the anchors have a long name so it looks like this:

[image]

I need format them like the first image. (Note: I am **not** using `<li>` elements)

Comment: So you want the text to break and buttons to stay in the same position?

Comment: yes, I need EDIT and VIEW  button in same position

Comment: Why do you have two different buttons inside the same link?

Comment: @Α.Papadakis : I need this format only

Comment: The buttons supposed to have a specific action. At this moment you have three items inside the same link.

Answer (score 0):

Please fix your HTML, you don't add buttons to an anchor tag... Instead I've fixed it for you, try this.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <a href="#withTagEle"><i class="fa fa-male"></i></span> 10.58.1D.50.1F.FB</a>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <button class="btn-xs pull-right showOnHover viewInfoOfElement">View</button> 
      <button class="btn-xs pull-right showOnHover editElementInfo">Edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer-container::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.outer-container > .inner-container {
  float: right;
}

.outer-container > a {
  float: left;
}
```

link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g136vw08/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is your span tag

```
<a href="#withTagEle"><i 
  class="fa fa-male"></i></span> 10.58.1D.50.1F.FB
  <button class="btn-xs pull-right showOnHover viewInfoOfElement">View</button> 
  <button class="btn-xs pull-right showOnHover editElementInfo">Edit</button>
</a>
```

This is new HTML hope this code work with you

HTML

```
<a class="content" href="#withTagEle">
<i class="fa fa-male"></i><span> 10.58.1D.50.1F.FB</span>
<button class="btn-xs pull-right showOnHover viewInfoOfElement">View</button> 
<button class="btn-xs pull-right showOnHover editElementInfo">Edit</button>
</a>
```

CSS

```
a.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
button.btn-xs.pull-right.showOnHover.viewInfoOfElement {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please leave a comment if is doesn't work.

```css
a {
    display: flex; 
    text-decoration:none;
}
.btn-xs{
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="#withTagEle">
 <i class="fa fa-male"></i>
 <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    </span>
 <button class="btn-xs pull-right showOnHover viewInfoOfElement">View</button>
 <button class="btn-xs pull-right showOnHover editElementInfo">Edit</button>
</a>
```